# Converting forwarded email from HTML body to Plain text following by converting to HTML text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to convert a forwarded email body from HTML text to Plain text first (so that all the links, icons & images are gone) and again convert it to HTML text, then send the mail using VBA macro.

I am trying with the below given code for the task, but somehow I am not getting my desired result, which I am getting while doing the same task manually.

```
olMail.Body = olMail.Body 'To convert the HTML body text to Plain Text

olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'To convert the changed plain text to HTML text
```

Please suggest if I have to add anything else or need to modify the code. Also please suggest if I have to change any settings in Outlook also? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain 'To convert the HTML body text to Plain Text`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! However, converting HTML to Plain text, both olMail.Body = olMail.Body and olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain are giving me the same result..

Comment: You probably want something like `olMail.HTMLBody = olMail.Body`, but I don't know if you can do something like that without some further transformation to the HTMLBody text